# Identifying capital letters in a string and the position

Tags: java, regex, string, character

So i have a string H

and I want to scan the string and check if the letter at a point is Capital and if it is: store the position of that capital letter in an array.

I believe Regex is the tool I want to use but I'm unable to decipher how it works.

is there any way to do something like:

```
int i = 0;
int j = 0;
int length = H.length()
int[] positionalarray = new int[length];
while(i < length)
{
   if(H[i]isCapital) //or something along those lines:
   {
       positionalarray[j] = i;
       j++;
   }
}
```

where the crux of the solution is 'what is the correct syntax to simulate' H[i]isCapital

Comment: You need to learn how Java `String`s work first, using a basics Java tutorial. After that, you're looking for `Character.isUpperCase()`.

Comment: [Regex101](http://regex101.com/) is a nice tool that might help you to figure out what you are trying to do with regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is

```
Character.isUpperCase(H.charAt(i));
```

Answer (score 0):

The java regex [Pattern class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) provides this. This also supports non ascii uppercase letters using the [unicode uppercase character category](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Lu/list.htm).

```
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\p{Lu}");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("A string containing these letters: Ä Æ É.");
    while (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.format("Position: %d, letter: %s\n", matcher.start(), matcher.group());
    }
```